# An error is generated regarding 'lvalue'.what is the reason?

Tags: c

I want to make a program to check if there are any numbers, uppercase and lowercase letters in my password.But,an error about 'lvalue' will occur when this code is executed. What is the reason?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
     char passwd[99];
     printf("make a password:");
     gets_s(passwd,99);

     int num_count = 0, up_count = 0, down_count = 0;

     while(1)
     { 
     for (int i = 0; passwd[i] != NULL; i++)
     {
         if ('0' <= passwd[i] && passwd[i] <= '9')
             num_count++;
         else if ('a' <= passwd[i] && passwd[i] <= 'z')
         {
             down_count++;
         }
         else if ('A' <= passwd[i] && passwd[i] <= 'Z')
         {
             up_count++;
         }
     }
     if (num_count == 0 || up_count == 0 || down_count = 0)
         printf("make the password again!");
     else
     {

         break;
     }
     }

     getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include the error message!

Comment: Do you mean when compiled? I don't see any lvalue messages at run time.

Comment: ... fully, verbatim and as text directly here, please.

Comment: Re "*`printf("make the password again!");`*", It would be better to say the requirements and/or what needs to be fixed.

Comment: There are two more errors beside the answer: `passwd[i] != NULL;` should be `passwd[i] != 0;` and you must `#include <conio.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
num_count == 0 || up_count == 0 || down_count = 0
```

should be

```
num_count == 0 || up_count == 0 || down_count == 0
```

---

To explain the error, the statement you have is equivalent to the following:

```
( num_count == 0 || up_count == 0 || down_count ) = 0
```

An expression that can be found on the left-hand side of an assignment is called an lvalue, and the expression in parens is not a valid lvalue.